# JSF 2.1 inputText type attribute

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, input, xhtml

We are working with JSF 2.1, and upgrading to JSF 2.2 is not an option at this time. For our application forms, I want to be able to add a type attribute to the inputText tags, so that mobile users will be presented with the correct keyboard for the data they are about to enter.

```
<h:inputText id="textID" type="text" value=""></h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="phoneNum" type="tel" value=""></h:inputText>
<h:inputText id="email" type="email" value=""></h:inputText>
```

How can I make this following rendered HTML happen with JSF 2.1?

```
<input id="textID" type="text" value=""/>
<input id="phoneNum" type="tel" value=""/>
<input id="email" type="email" value=""/>
```

Comment: `type` is not valid attribute of `h:inputText` in JSF 2.1. In HTML you cannot put any data in `type`, it supports only `type="button|checkbox|file|hidden|image|password|radio|reset|submit|text"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make this following rendered HTML happen with JSF 2.1?

- So for the first one ( type=text ) its given by default by using **h:inputText** tag.
- for the athors you can use Validator to validate your expression , for example to validate email address with regular expression ,the same for  type=tel

See more about validator email example here [email validator example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/)

---

Or you can use primefaces inputText tag that make you able to use : tel , email as value of the attribut **type** like this :

```
<p:inputText type="email" value="#{userBean.userName}" />

<p:inputText type="tel" value="#{userBean.telephone}" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Using primefaces worked for me AND as a plus, I am now able to use placeholders as well!